# Comparing large lists of hashes

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I have 2 lists. One is a list of MD5 and SHA1 hashes from files from a computer I have (ListA). The other is a list of MD5 and SHA1 hashes I have downloaded form NSRL (ListB). Its a compilation of MD5 and SHA1 hashes from files included in many different applications.

I am trying to find a quick way to compare these lists to each other.

Just for the reference of performance, the hashes from the system is a 7.2gb text file and the NSRL hash list is approximately 20gb. I have a system with 32gb of ram to perform the processing, so it should have enough memory to load both files into memory if need be.

I've looked into [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908822%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and also considered reading each line in from the ListA and comparing it to ListB, but there has to be a better way than this. Any ideas?

Also, this is a comparison of the hashes from a machine to known hashes from a hash database. Its pretty common practice in forensics (from what I understand), so I'm open to the suggestion of applications that exist to do this already.

Comment: I'm curious to learn what this will be used for

Comment: You might consider sorting your lists first. Then compare them using approach similar to merge sort.

Comment: @Phillippe Leybaert, This is a common forensics practice when looking for files on a system. Get an MD5/SHA1 has of every file, compare it to a list of known good files (or sometimes compare it to a list of known bad files) and see what stands out.

Comment: @Sugitime I understand it's a common forensics practice, but I'm still curious what ***your*** use case is.

Comment: @Phillippe Leybaert, Its some class work. Take the image of a system, get the hashes (I used ftimes), compare the hashes to NSLR db. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Using a hash would be fastest but you don't have enough memory to load all of those items into a hash. Assuming the number of SHA-1 and MD5 entries are divided equally, you would have approximately 500 million entries in ListA and 1 billion in ListB. That would be at least 8 billion bytes assuming 8 byte pointers each.

Instead, you should use a [Radix Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_prefix_tree) to store just ListB first, then perform the comparison as you're reading ListA. It doesn't perform as well as a hash but it's a good space-time trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class that can hold the data of a single hash item
2. Make sure it implements GetHashCode and Equals correctly.
3. Create 2 [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s of the type you created, one for ListA and one for ListB.
4. Load all items form the lists to the hashsets.
5. Use [`SymmetricExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which takes O(n))to get all the hashes that aren't in both lists.

---

```
var setA = new HashSet<Item>(LoadListA());
var setB = new HashSet<Item>(LoadListb());
setA.SymmetricExceptWith(setB);

if (setA.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Extra items ןn A or B");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSets. Firstly load all the items from both lists into `HashSet`s. Then us `IntersectWith` which will take O(n).

Pretty sure, the bottleneck in your case would be reading data from files into memory. In terms of performance I will suggest read text files into memory and then parse it.